# Password matching regular expression does not work in IE 6 & 7

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm using the Asp.net change password control in my application and all seems to be find 
But there is a error occurs when validating the password.(Validation fails only in IE 6 & 7)

Here is the regex I'm using:

```
^(?!\d)(?!.*(.)\1)(?=.*\d)[\w\d$@#]{8,10}$
```

Comment: The Password does not validate according to the regex.Even though we entered the correct password it gives it as invalid password

Comment: Which password does it fail to validate?

Comment: By the way, those are some seriously weird password restrictions.

Comment: @Tim probably they did not read [the XKCD hint sheet](http://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: This validation fails for every password i entered only in IE 6 & 7 versions).not for others(IE8, Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

The Password does not validate according to the regex.Even though we entered the correct password it gives it as invalid password